# Convert data into a DataFrame with format as a mix of dictionary and tuple

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Following is an example of result of my code. I want to convert the part in a dictionary into a DataFrame, I don't know how to perform it, can any one help me please?

```
x = ([('f', 66)], {('f', 66): ([('ft', 88, "@", '592063472')])},
   [('x', 12)], {('x', 12): ([('uuuu', 9, "dd", '592063472')])})
x

The data frame that I want
0    1     2     3    4     5
f   66     ft   88    @    592063472
x   12     uuu   9   dd    592063472
```

Comment: How should the dataframe look like?

Comment: I will put and example now

Comment: The header is not important write now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

approach.

1. find the dictionary instances
2. build a list of tuples.

```
import pandas as pd
x_data=[d for d in x if isinstance(d,(dict))] # first loop , find if it's instance of dictionary
x_data=[(e1 + e[e1][0]) for e in x_data for e1 in e ] # 2nd loop, build a list of tuples
df=pd.DataFrame(x_data_1) # create the dataframe.
df
```

output:
[image]